# Postgres autogenerated table column with Unaccent, use trigger?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am making a Postgres table that stores book information. I have a "title" column for which data is manually entered but I would like to create an autogenerated column "title_no_diacritics" that uses the Unaccent extension to strip diacritics from the titles. Is this best done with a trigger?

Comment: A trigger is the only choice you have

Comment: Ok, thanks, I am trying to decide whether it is better to strip diacritics in the DB, on the backend or even on the front (this is for prettified URLS). I just get the feeling that triggers are to be avoided if at all possible, is that accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trigger is the correct solution, particularly since it is very low-level, data-centric processing.

You can use the `unaccent()` function from the ["unaccent" contrib module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unaccent.html).

Comment: How can I use unaccent for trigger ? Because when I use, I receive error: "Syntax error". Here is my code:
`     CREATE TRIGGER tsv_update_books BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
      ON books FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
      tsvector_update_trigger(
        tsv_search, 'pg_catalog.english', book_name, SELECT unaccent('unaccent', book_name);
      );
`

Comment: You can only pass constants as arguments in `CREATE TRIGGER`.